# numpy array is printed into file with unwanted wrapping

Tags: python, numpy

I have a number of lengthy vectors like below:

```
a = np.array([ 57.78307975,  80.69239616,  80.9268784,   62.03157284,  61.57220483,  67.99433377,  68.18790282])
```

When I print it into file with:

```
outfile.write(str(a))
# or
outfile.write(np.array_str(a))
```

It automatically wraps the middle of a line up and it makes the vector occupy two lines:

```
[ 57.78307975  80.69239616  80.9268784   62.03157284  61.57220483
  67.99433377  68.18790282]
```

The wrapped line has a width of 66. I'm not sure whether this value is related with a width of terminal screen.

I just want to see a vector be printed in a single line. How can I make it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because the default print option "linewidth" is 75:

```
>>> np.get_printoptions()['linewidth']
75
```

To disable wrapping you can set the linewidth to infinite with [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html):

```
>>> str(a)
'[57.78307975 80.69239616 80.9268784  62.03157284 61.57220483 67.99433377\n 68.18790282]'
>>> np.set_printoptions(linewidth=np.inf)
>>> str(a)
'[57.78307975 80.69239616 80.9268784  62.03157284 61.57220483 67.99433377 68.18790282]'
```

For a once-off override, without needing to alter the global options:

```
>>> np.array2string(a, max_line_width=np.inf)
'[57.78307975 80.69239616 80.9268784  62.03157284 61.57220483 67.99433377 68.18790282]'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! But how does it work? Why is newline character inserted into the very certain place?

Comment: If you just want to print out, you can just use: np.set_printoptions(linelength=np.inf) before printing. Just adding this here for future reference. Why does it do this? Well linelength by default is set to 75 by whoever wrote python, things longer than that get wrapped automagically. Not a decision that I would have made personally, as it slows everything down and is a pain to parse, and results in unpredictable output.

Comment: @Owl There is no "linelength" option for `np.set_printoptions`. And the right option, "linewidth", is already mentioned in this answer.

Comment: alas on the Windows box I'm using at least np.info translates to 1024 chars. It still wraps at 1024 chars ... grrrr. How hard can it be to ask for no frigging line wrap ... Even with stupidly long lines, as in really, np.inf!

Comment: I stand corrected! I checked with ahex editor and it's the text editors I was using (Windows default notepad and Atom) which are wrapping at 1024 even when line wrap is off. So I downloaded klogg and am good, it doesn't such naughtiness.